# Check authorize(Role) inside controller in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a controller in my project .

```
         [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        private StudentRepositor obj = new StudentRepositor();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var model = obj.GetStudentlist();
            foreach (var stu in model)
            {
                stu.State = (stu.State == "1") ? "فعال" : "غیرفعال ";
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

I want to check the permission inside my controller not outside .

For example some thing like this :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
            {

               if(Role=admin) return view2
               if(role=teacher) return view1
            }
```

Can i do something like this ?!!

Best regards

Comment: you need to use Custom Authorization attribue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958304/verify-user-permission-on-action-filter-or-authroize-filter/22535997

Comment: in that you can return view or action on basis of role

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use `User.IsInRole()`

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

           if(User.IsInRole("admin")) 
           {
               //Return View
           }
           else if(User.IsInRole("teacher")) 
           {
               //Return View
           }
           else
           {
               //Return View
           }
        }
```

Comment: How to do this in a View? The `IsInRole` method doesn't get recognized. In The controller everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create your custom AuthorizationAttribute, something like this.

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly Type _userType;

        public AuthorizationAttribute()
        {
        }

        public AuthorizationAttribute(Type userType)
        {
            _userType = userType;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var currentHttpContext = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
            if (!currentHttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //Redirect 
            }

            if (_userType != null)
            {
                var identity = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                //Get type for identity

                if(_userType != identityType)
                {
                     //Redirect
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

After that you can use it like this:

```
[Authorization(typeof(Admin))]
public ActionResult Create()
{}
```