# Using both Forms and AD authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory

My ASP.NET MVC site requires forms-based authentication for some resources (downloads, discussion forum, etc). This works great with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

However, I need my admin site (`~/Areas/Admin/*) to authenticate against active directory.

With regular ASP.NET or classic ASP, I would just go into the IIS config and change the directory security to deny anonymous users. However, I can't figure out a way to do that with an area.

I know putting the `[authorize]` attribute on the controllers in my admin area would require a login, but it'll use the same forms-based authorization as the public areas of the site. Right now that authenticates users against a database  (not using the ASP.NET Membership system as it's overkill for my app). I need users to authenticate against the domain, but ONLY in the Admin area.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own custom Domain authorize attribute and add this to the admin controllers.

Have a look at the answer here: [asp.net mvc Adding to the AUTHORIZE attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554094/asp-net-mvc-adding-to-the-authorize-attribute)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does anyone have something more specifically applicable to LDAP/Active Directory?