# Redirect From Action Filter Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, routes

What is the best way to do a redirect in an `ActionFilterAttribute`.  I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` called `IsAuthenticatedAttributeFilter` and that checked the value of a session variable.  If the variable is false, I want the application to redirect to the login page.  I would prefer to redirect using the route name `SystemLogin` however any redirect method at this point would be fine.

Comment: **[Check this answer. Hope this will help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18126733/2015869)**

Answer (score 207, accepted):

**Set filterContext.Result**

With the route name:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("SystemLogin", routeValues);
```

You can also do something like:

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = SharedViews.SessionLost,
    ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData
};
```

---

If you want to use `RedirectToAction`:

You could make a public `RedirectToAction` method on your controller (*preferably on its base controller*) that simply calls the protected `RedirectToAction` from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.  Adding this method allows for a public call to *your* `RedirectToAction` from the filter.

```
public new RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string action, string controller)
{
    return base.RedirectToAction(action, controller);
}
```

Then your filter would look something like:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var controller = (SomeControllerBase) filterContext.Controller;
    filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("index", "home");
}
```

Comment: This works, but shouldn't there be a RedirectToAction method available?

Comment: @BenMills there is, however, it's `protected` so you wouldn't have access to it from the filter.

Comment: My question now is why did Microsoft decide to make this filter `protected` there must be some reasonable explanation? I feel very dirty redefining this accessibility of `RedirectToAction` without understanding why it was encapsulated in the first place.

Comment: @MatthewMarlin - See the answer by Syakur for the right answer for redirecting to an action. You are correct that you should not be calling a controller directly from an action filter - that is the definition of tight coupling.

Comment: This will bypass other filters, is there anyway to avoid that? I have other necessary filters in the pipe line which must be executed after this filter's result.

Comment: @Akbari have you tried setting the Order property of the attributes? Also FilterScope wil impact execution order.

Comment: @MatthewMarlin Maybe redirectToAction is restricted on filters because the filter will execute again and again with the redirect, falling into an infinite loop.

Comment: I tried this and started getting errors from the _Layout which had an @Html.Action on it.. *sigh*

Comment: Helpful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214774/how-to-redirect-from-onactionexecuting-in-base-controller

Answer (score 85):

Alternatively to a redirect, if it is calling your own code, you could use this:

```
actionContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Error" })
);

actionContext.Result.ExecuteResult(actionContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
```

It is not a pure redirect but gives a similar result without unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Note that you should not be calling `actionContext.Result.ExecuteResult` from within your action filter - MVC will do that automatically after the action filter runs (provided `actionContext.Result` is not null).

Answer (score 13):

I am using MVC4, I used following approach to redirect a custom html screen upon authorization breach.

Extend `AuthorizeAttribute` say `CutomAuthorizer`
override the `OnAuthorization` and `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`

Register the `CustomAuthorizer` in the `RegisterGlobalFilters`.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{

    filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizer());
}
```

upon identifying the `unAuthorized` access call `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`and redirect to the concerned controller action as shown below.

---

```
public class CustomAuthorizer : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = IsAuthorized(filterContext); // check authorization
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        if (!isAuthorized && !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("Unauthorized", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            && !filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.Equals("LogOn", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {

            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

        }
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result =
       new RedirectToRouteResult(
           new RouteValueDictionary{{ "controller", "LogOn" },
                                          { "action", "Unauthorized" }

                                         });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you want to re-implement, or possibly extend, `AuthorizeAttribute`. If so, you should make sure that you inherit that, and not `ActionFilterAttribute`, in order to let ASP.NET MVC do more of the work for you.

Also, you want to make sure that you authorize *before* you do any of the real work in the action method - otherwise, the only difference between logged in and not will be what page you see when the work is done.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Do whatever checking you need here

        // If you want the base check as well (against users/roles) call
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

There is a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554094/asp-net-mvc-adding-to-the-authorize-attribute) with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554094/asp-net-mvc-adding-to-the-authorize-attribute/554121#554121) with more details here on SO.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following snippet, it should be pretty clear:

```
public class AuthorizeActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(FilterExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
    Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

    if (controller != null)
    {
      if (session["Login"] == null)
      {
        filterContext.Cancel = true;
        controller.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("./Login");
      }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I had to check query string values if any user tries to change query string values and tries to access data which is not authorized to him/her than I am redirecting them to unauthorized message page, using ActionFilterAttribute.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me (asp.net core 2.1)

```
using JustRide.Web.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace MyProject.Web.Filters
{
    public class IsAuthenticatedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult(nameof(AccountController.Index), "Account", null);
        }
    }
}



[AllowAnonymous, IsAuthenticated]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that also takes in account if you are using Ajax requests.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace YourNamespace{        
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AuthorizeCustom : ActionFilterAttribute {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
            if (YourAuthorizationCheckGoesHere) {               
                string area = "";// leave empty if not using area's
                string controller = "ControllerName";
                string action = "ActionName";
                var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);                  
                if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()){ // Check if Ajax
                    if(area == string.Empty)
                        context.HttpContext.Response.Write($"<script>window.location.reload('{urlHelper.Content(System.IO.Path.Combine(controller, action))}');</script>");
                    else
                        context.HttpContext.Response.Write($"<script>window.location.reload('{urlHelper.Content(System.IO.Path.Combine(area, controller, action))}');</script>");
                } else   // Non Ajax Request                      
                    context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary( new{ area, controller, action }));             
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could inherit your controller then use it inside your action filter

inside your ActionFilterAttribute class:

```
   if( filterContext.Controller is MyController )
      if(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["login"] == null)
           (filterContext.Controller as MyController).RedirectToAction("Login");
```

inside your base controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    public void  RedirectToAction(string actionName) { 
        base.RedirectToAction(actionName); 
    }
}
```

Cons. of this is to change all controllers to inherit from "MyController" class