# How to run some code in every ActionResult method and return result if necessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, initialization, actionresult

I need to run a certain function in every `ActionResult` and return a certain value if necessary.

Let's say this function's name is `A()`. I can do this manually:

```
ActionResult Index() {
     if (...) return A();
     ...
}

ActionResult About() {
     if (...) return A();
}
```

Or I can use the `Initialize()` method:

```
override void Initialize(RequestContext r) {
    A(); // Can't do a return here
}
```

But the problem is that I can't return an `ActionResult` value since it's void.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (...) {
            // modify filterContext as needed
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add `[MyActionFilter]` to controllers and/or actions

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I need. And how do I return a certain ActionResult (for example, RedirectToAction())?

Comment: You use `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url)`. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5453371/291687) answer for more examples.

Comment: Works perfectly! Overriding this method in controller itself will allow to modify context result in all actions of this controller automatically.