# Handling Session in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an website there all user information is stored in Session. But if the Session is expired, is there an way to redirect to the user back to login instead of giving me an error. The problem is worst in the View where it's used to display username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an action filter that checks the users session and redirects if they need to login. [This Question May Help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/asp-net-mvc-3-redirect-from-action-filter-attribute)