# what is the use of RouteValueDictonary routeValues in Html.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(new RouteValueDictionary { {"Action","Index"}}))
{
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

When I render

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method="post"><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Is this the actual use of RouteValueDictonary. If so I can do this do by HTML.BeginForm("About","Home")

Can some one explain the actual use of RouteValueDictonary.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is also useful when implementing the `ActionFilterAttribute` for Redirection purpose. The basic usage of this class is to define the `Action` name, `Controller` Name and `Area` Name

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filtercontext)
    {
        filtercontext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult
            (
                new RouteValueDictionary
                    (
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "ControllerName",
                            action = "ActionName",
                            area = "AreaName"
                        }
                    )
            );
        base.OnResultExecuting(filtercontext);
    }
}
```

You can also send the Parameter list like below..

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                            {"action", "ActionName"},
                            {"controller", "ControllerName"},
                            {"area", "Area Name"},
                            {"Parameter Name","Parameter Value"}
                        });
```

Answer (score 7):

The route value dictionary simply allows flexibility in defining the location that the form will POST to.  Not everyone stops at controller/action.  For example, let's say that I wanted my form to post to `/Area/Controller/FormProcessor/Action/Parameter1/Parameter2`.  I cannot do this by using the simple `Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")` method.