# How to return 404 page in ASP .NET MVC when query string parameters is incorrect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's imagine I have the following action

```
public ViewResult Products(string color)
{...}
```

and route which maps url "products" to this action.

According to SEO tips link `/products?color=red` should return

> 200 OK

But link `/products?someOtherParametr=someValue`

> 404 Not found

So the question is - how to handle unexisting query parameters and return 404 in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Validate this before executing the Action Method. This approach is valid for all Controller of you project or specific Action method.**

**Controller Action Methods**

```
[attr]  // Before executing any Action Method, Action Filter will execute to 
        //check for Valid Query Strings.
public class ActionResultTypesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int Param = 0)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel obj)
    {
        return View(obj);
    }

}
```

**Action Filter**

```
public class attr : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.Count == 0 &&
                  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
        {
              //When no Action Parameter exists and Query String exists. 
        }
        else
        {
            // Check the Query String Key name and compare it with the Action 
            // Parameter name
            foreach (var item in System.Web.HttpContext
                                       .Current
                                       .Request.QueryString.Keys)
            {
                if (!filterContext.ActionParameters.Keys.Contains(item))
                {
                    // When the Query String is not matching with the Action 
                    // Parameter
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

*If you pay attention to the above code, we are checking the Action parameter as shown in the screen show below.*

[image]

### [**What can we do in case the QueryString passed does not exists in the Action Method Parameter? We can redirect the user to another page as shown in this link.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126733/2015869)

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                            {"action", "ActionName"},
                            {"controller", "ControllerName"},
                            {"area", "Area Name"},
                            {"Parameter Name","Parameter Value"}
                        });
```

Or

We can do like this. The below mentioned code will be written in the `OnActionExecuting` Method Override

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);
```

Comment: Works fine, but we have troubles when we have complex objects in action parameters

Comment: can u give an example ?

Answer (score 6):

Considering the accepted answer at [What is the proper way to send an HTTP 404 response from an ASP.NET MVC action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499817/what-is-the-proper-way-to-send-an-http-404-response-from-an-asp-net-mvc-action), there is a special `ActionResult` that could fulfill your expectation.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Products(string color)
    {
        if (color != "something") // it can be replaced with any guarded clause(s)
            return new HttpNotFoundResult("The color does not exist.");
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Products(string color)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.Count != 1 || 
            Request.QueryString.GetKey(0) != "color")
            return new HttpNotFoundResult("the error message");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote about url /products?someOtherParametr=someValue
not about /products?color=something

Comment: I have written in the answer, "it can be replaced with any guarded clause(s)"; so, you can check whether appropriate parameter(s) is provided or not by checking QueryString object. It's very simple. Do you want me to update the answer?

Comment: Yes, please. Will be very appreciate for it

Comment: Thanks, but I found more flexible way

Comment: I've been looking for something simple like this for a long time - never knew this existed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var actionParameters = filterContext.ActionParameters.Keys;
    var queryParameters = filterContext
                                  .RequestContext
                                  .HttpContext
                                  .Request
                                  .QueryString
                                  .Keys;

    // if we pass to action any query string parameter which doesn't 
    // exists in action we should return 404 status code

    if(queryParameters.Cast<object>().Any(queryParameter 
                                 => !actionParameters.Contains(queryParameter)))
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);
}
```

Actually, if you don't want to write this is in every controller, you should override DefaultControllerFactory

Answer (score 0):

This works in Asp.Net Core.
In Controller ActionMethods use below one liner code:

```
return StatusCode(404, "Not a valid request.");
```

In OnActionExecuting method, set StatusCode to context.Result as in below sample:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    string color = HttpContext.Request?.Query["color"].ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(color))
    {
        // invalid or no color param, return 404 status code
        context.Result = StatusCode(200, "Not a valid request.");
    }
    else
    {
        // write logic for any common functionality
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```