# MVC 5 - Redirect to a controller from anywhere

Tags: redirect, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, extension-methods, actionresult

I am developing a MVC 5 internet application, and I wish to redirect to a controller/action result from anywhere in my application.

The controller name is "Manager", and the action result is "TestAction"

In an action result, the following code can be used:

```
RedirectToAction("TestAction", "Manager")
```

I have also coded a filter attribute as follows:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult( new RouteValueDictionary{{ "controller", "Manage" }, { "action", "TestAction" } });
```

Is there a generic way to send the user to a specific controller, action result from anywhere in a MVC application? I specifically wish to do this in an extension method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by simply `Response.Redirect` (taking the domain path and append the url).

Did you try the answer like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126733/713789

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to redirect from an extension method?

Comment: Yes, Through Pass context. Remember it's must be done before Response.End

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by through Pass context?

Comment: Where is your Extension method ?, If you are in Controller or Global.Asax then you can try Filtercontext ,RequestContext,ControllerContext

Comment: The extension method is in a static class called ExtensionMethods.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can use RedirectToAction("TestAction", "Manager") to redirect and in your view you can write windows.location.href("Manager","TestAction").

Answer (score 0):

What i've done in such cases:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
//
//...add parameters...

dictionary.Add("controller", "ControllerName");//ex: Home for HomeController
dictionary.Add("action", "MyMethod");
return RedirectToRoute("Default", dictionary);//"Default" is the name of the rout you're using
```