# How to get redirect to a specific url from basecontroller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have HomeController and a BaseController and a method in a BaseController from where I need to redirect to a specific URL.

Here is the code: -

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       VerfiySomething();

       CodeLine1.....
       CodeLine2.....
       CodeLineN.....
    }
}
```

Here is base Controller -

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public void VerfiySomething()
    {
       if(based_on_some_check)
       {
           Redirect(myurl);
       }
    }
}
```

But the codeline1,2...N gets executed in HomeController even after executing "Redirect(myurl)" in BaseController

What I want is that it should get redirect to some other URL (not to any other action) without executing CodeLin1,2...N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would implement an [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx).

See: [Redirect From Action Filter Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute)

```
public class VerifySomethingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (based_on_some_check)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[VerifySomething]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could verify that something in the controller's virtual method `OnActionExecuting`:

```
class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (somethingWrong)
        {
            context.Result = GetSomeUnhappyResult();
        }
    }
}
```