# Removing /Index from end of browser URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm a bit rusty on my MVC routing.

I'm using a default route of

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Default",
        action = "Index",
    });
```

I have a controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
```

So, typically, this can be hit with either `http://mydomain/Some/Index` -or- `http://mydomain/Some`

On this particular controller, I'd like to either deny (404) ~/Some/Index or simply redirect ~/Some/Index to ~/Some.

This is relatively easy to accomplish in the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var p = Request.Url.Segments;
    var last = p.Last();
    if(string.Equals(last, "index", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");
    }
```

but now it seems like the controller is getting polluted by cross-cutting concerns. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are much cleaner ways -

Option 1 - [You can use HTtpModule for Permanant redirection](http://www.jameswampler.com/2010/12/14/managing-301-moved-permanently-redirects-in-asp-net/)

Option 2 - [Use UrlRewriter](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RedirectingASPNETLegacyURLsToExtensionlessWithTheIISRewriteModule.aspx)

Option 3 - [You can also implement an Action Filter in which you can redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

So, if I add another route above the default route that dumps this specific url onto a non-existent controller/action, then I get a lovely 404. Perfect.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SomeIndexDeny",
    "Some/Index",
    new
    {
        controller = "NonExistentController",
        action = "NonExistentMethod"
    });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Default",
        action = "Index",
    });
```