# asp.net mvc validate [HttpPost] ActionResult()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to implement a ActionFilterAttribute `[POST]` ActionResult() in the controller. The problem is that I try to “redirect” to a page if validation failed... But it does not work. Validation runs, but then returns to the `ActionResult()` next line and finally when the view is returned, only then “redirected” to the page listed in the validation. Ultimately what I need is to stop the ActionResult() statements and “redirect” to the page listed in the validation. I tried `OnActionExecuting()` and `OnActionExecuted()` but does not work any

I need to...

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect (loginUrl, true);
```

Run away, “redirecting” the page indicated

My code:

```
[HelperSomeValidations("")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Pais pais)
{
  try
  {
    PaisBLL.saveNew(pais);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) 
  {
    ViewBag.error = ex;
    return View(“Error”);
  }
  return RedirectToAction(“Index”);
}

public class HelperSomeValidations : ActionFilterAttribute
{

  public HelperSomeValidations(String permiso)
  {
    this.permiso = permiso;
  }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    var user = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["coco"];
    if (user == null) //validates if the user just login
    {
      //send them off to the login page
      var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
      var loginUrl = url.Content(“~/Usuario/Login”);
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
    }
    else
    {
      if (permission != “”)
      {
        //does some validations with “permission”
      }
    }
 }
```

}

Thks!

Comment: Do you **have** to use an action filter? I can post an example using `AuthorizeAttribute` which seems it would suit better here.

Comment: @webnoob: `AuthorizeAttribute` and `ActionFilterAttribute` are both  `FilterAttribute`s. The same principles apply to both.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Oops, there goes that terminology thing again ... Thanks. I'll leave the comment in place in case anyone else gets confused :)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true)`, you need to set the [`filterContext.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.result(v=vs.118).aspx) to a `RedirectResult`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't solve the problem you have posted but I feel it's a better solution. I would personally use an `AuthoriseAttribute` here instead as this is what it's designed todo.

```
public class Authorise : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string _permissionSystemName;

    public Authorise()
    {
    }

    public Authorise(string permissionSystemName)
    {
        _permissionSystemName = permissionSystemName;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //DO some logic and return True or False based on whether they are allowed or not.

        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    area = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["area"],
                    controller = "Generic",
                    action = "PermissionDenied"
                })
            );
    }
}
```

Usage would be along the lines of:

```
[Authorise("SomePermissionName")]
public class MyController : Controller
{

}
```