# asp.net mvc ActionFilterAttribute - redirect to "controller/action/parameter"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

My previous problem was solved  [asp.net mvc validate [HttpPost] ActionResult()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616674/asp-net-mvc-validate-httppost-actionresult)

Right!. Now I need to redirect to "controller/action/parameter" from OnActionExecuting() method in  ActionFilterAttribute Helper Class. In line

```
public class HelperSeguridad : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
   .
   . 
   .    
    if (permission != “”)
          {
            redirect "HERE"
          }
  }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public class PaisController : Controller
{
.
.

  public ActionResult Error(Exception ex)
  {
     ViewBag.error = ex;
     return View();
  }

}
```

Thks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
new RouteValueDictionary {
    { "action", "login" },
    { "controller", "persons" },
    { "someQuerystring", "someValue" }
}
);
```

Comment: can't execute RedirectToAction() from an ActionFilterAttribute Class

Comment: how I declare generic manner {"controller", "xxxxx"} references the controller's ActionResult that executed the ActionFilter?