# How to redirect to login page if session is not available in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing ASP.Net MVC 5.0 application, . Now I have created login page. when user is valid I am storing user details into seesion.

```
        if(_loginmodel.authstatus == false)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        Session["authstatus"] = true;
        Session["userid"] = _loginmodel.userid;
        Session["useremail"] = _loginmodel.useremail;
        Session["username"] = _loginmodel.username;
```

No when user go to other files I am again checking session available or not

```
  public class CityController : Controller
    {

    private CityModels _citymodel;

    #region Constructor
    public CityController()
    {
        if (Session != null && Session["authstatus"] != null)
        {
            _citymodel = new CityModels();

        }
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
    #endregion
   }
```

so now  how can i redirect him to login page if session expired

Comment: You can't do that in a constructor.  Use action filters.

Comment: @David: No.  That method has no side-effects.

Comment: no RedirectToAction() is not working.. how can i use action filters? #slaks

Comment: can u please give me example or suggest me where to check session

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd410209

Comment: i am not getting how to use action filter in this context. can u please brief me how to pass this reuirement. thnaks in advance

Comment: How do you propose differentiating between "session expired" and "entirely new session"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could wrap this logic inside an action filter, and redirect in there:

```
    public class AuthorizeActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(FilterExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

        if (controller != null)
        {
          if (session != null && session ["authstatus"] == null)
          {
filterContext.Result =
       new RedirectToRouteResult(
           new RouteValueDictionary{{ "controller", "Login" },
                                          { "action", "Index" }

                                         });
          }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
    }
```

more details in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453371/1384539

Comment: Not worked for me. I load page using partialview via AJAX and this approach not worked (the code does not hit to here when session is expired) :( Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

1. Write code in web.config file to set the session timeout to 2 minutes

   ```xml
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
       <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="1" />
       </authentication>
       <sessionState timeout="2"></sessionState>
       <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
   </system.web>
   ```
2. Write the code below in a `<script>` tag in layout.cshtml

   ```
   //session end 
   var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout - 1;
   var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
   setTimeout('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);

   function SessionEnd() {
       window.location.hostname = "";
       /* $(window.Location).attr("href", "@Url.Content("~/Login/index/")"); */
       window.location = "/Login/index/";
   }
   ```
3. Write the code below in control and action

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Logout()
   { 
       Session["id1"] = null;
       Session["id2"] = null;
       Session["id3"] = null;
       Session["id4"] = null;
       Session["Region"] = null;
       Session.Clear();           
       Session.RemoveAll();
       Session.Abandon();
       Response.AddHeader("Cache-control", "no-store, must-revalidate, private, no-cache");
       Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
       Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
       Response.AppendToLog("window.location.reload();");

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
   }
   ```

Comment: I would also do clearTimeout and reset the clock on every ajax call in the mvc application in ajaxStart or ajaxStop event of the document model.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom filter attribute to handle session expiry, as follows -

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom attribute for handling session timeout
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {
            // check if a new session id was generated
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Error/SessionTimeoutVeiw");
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now to use this custom attribute, decorate your controller method or class with this attribute.

`[SessionExpireFilterAttribute]`

And if you need to apply this filter to be applicable for all controllers, you can register this filter in FilterConfig file.

So when a session expires, so as the values in the session, you need not to check if a perticular session value has expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user to login page on Session_Start event in Global

```
protected void Session_Start()
        {            
            if (Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                //Redirect to Welcome Page if Session is not null  
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/WelcomeScreen", false);

            }
            else
            {
                //Redirect to Login Page if Session is null & Expires                   
                new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Index" }, { "controller", "Login" } });
            }
        }
```