# Redirect users back to login if the session expired on single page application

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a web application that is heavily ajax based. I only have one 2 views which is the login and the main view itself, and the rest are PartialViews that will be called using ajax requests.

If i put the session checkers inside the partialviews( through ActionFilters), it will return the login view and it will be displayed after my ajax is success which isn't my desired result since i want the mainpage itself to be redirected back to the login screen.

one solution that i think of is using a javascript timeout that will check if the session/authentication still exist given a set of intervals but i don't know if that practice is good.

Can someone suggest me what to do?

I have 2 views which is the `login` and the `mainframe` then around 30 `PartialViews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a Javascript timer in the past to poll the server to test if the session is still active. If I receive a 403 then redirect to the login page.

```
var AutoLogout = {}; 
AutoLogout.pollInterval = 60000; // Default is 1 minute.

// Force auto logout when session expires 
AutoLogout.start = function (heartBeatUrl, sessionExpiredUrl, interval) {
    if (interval) AutoLogout.pollInterval = interval; 

    var timer = $.timer(function() { 
        checkSession(heartBeatUrl, sessionExpiredUrl, timer); 
    }); 

    timer.set({ time: AutoLogout.pollInterval, autostart: true }); 
};

// Check the session serverside to see if we need to auto-logout 
// if the clientActivity flag is set then the session will be extended before checking. 
// if the session is still alive then set the next timer interval to be the time returned from the server. 
function checkSession(sessionUrl, sessionExpiredUrl, timer) {
    $.ajax(sessionUrl,
        { type: "post",
             contentType: "application/json",
             success: function (result) 
             { 
                 // update the timer poll interval based on return value.
                 try { 
                         var r = ko.toJS(result); 
                         timer.set({ 
                             time: r.TimeoutMilliseconds ? r.TimeoutMilliseconds : AutoLogout.pollInterval, autostart: true 
                         }); 
                 } 
                 catch(e) { } 
             }, 
             error: function(e) 
             {
                // do nothing 
             }, 
             statusCode: 
             { 
                403: function () 
                { 
                    window.location.href = sessionExpiredUrl; 
                },
                401: function () 
                { 
                    window.location.href = sessionExpiredUrl; 
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Then when you page loads call AutoLogout.start with the necessary url's for you application.

Notice: I have used Knockout JS in this example to parse the data returned from the server request but that is up to you.

Comment: i see, ill try try to use the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to solve your problem

I will suggest to put your logic in action filter

```
 public class AuthorizeActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(FilterExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

        if (controller != null)
        {
          if (session != null && session ["authstatus"] == null)
          {
filterContext.Result =
       new RedirectToRouteResult(
           new RouteValueDictionary{{ "controller", "Login" },
                                          { "action", "Index" }

                                         });
          }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
    }
```

also please refer this 
[Redirect From Action Filter Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute/5453371#5453371)

Comment: Already have this one, one problem is that this will redirect the child views but not the main view. Which means, i will get a different ajax result instead.

Comment: okk  , let me think of something @Mr. Bellis  logic is also good