# ASP.NET MVC route to return user to origin from partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2015. The app has the following structure:

- MyApp

  - Controllers

    - Controller1

      - Actions

        - Create
        - Delete
        - Details
        - Edit
        - IndexPartial
    - Controller2

      - Actions

        - Edit
    - Controller3

      - Actions

        - Edit
  - Views

    - Controller1

      - Create
      - Delete
      - Details
      - Edit
      - IndexPartial
    - Controller2

      - Edit
    - Controller3

      - Edit

The app displays `Controller1/IndexPartial` view on the `Controller2/Edit` view and on `Controller3/Edit`. This partial view displays rows of data, each with `Edit`, `Details`, `Delete` buttons which take the user to the `Controller1` views for those actions.

When the user is done with the Controller1 action, they need to return to `Controller2/Edit` or `Controller3/Edit` via the `Back to List` button or when the Save/Delete buttons are clicked. But how do we determine where the user originated? Did the user come from the `Edit` of `Controller2` or `Controller3`?

We've thought of using a session variable. Can `RouteConfig.cs` be used to track the user's path and help determine where s/he should return? How do we do this via routes in MVC?

Thank you for your help.

**Update:** This is all done via the server; no JavaScript (Angular, etc.).

Comment: Don't use Session variables for things like this. If the session times out (for whatever reason and there are plenty) your form will break. Instead simply pass a Parameter in the URI indicating the return page.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, thanks. Would the parameter require a change to the routes? Do you mind expounding on this a bit in an answer with an example?

Comment: I would not put this into the routes at all, because it makes those unnecessarily complex. You could simply pass a value (POST or GET) to the called endpoint (whatever route) and check for it in the Action method using the Request object. Maybe wrap this check in a helper object/method, so that you don't have to hardcode the name of the value each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routing engine has nothing to do with what you need. You need to track user navigation and a good way to do this is using ActionFilters.

You can create a custom ActionFilter that checks the UrlReferrer on its OnActionExecuted and decides how to redirect the request to the appropriate Controller/Action.

**[Example]**

ActionFilter

```
public class RedirectAfterActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // Your decision logic
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath == "something usefull")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Your Route Name", routeValues: null); // redirect to Home
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

ActionFilter usage

```
    [RedirectAfterActionFilter]
    public ActionResult DoSomethingAndGetRedirected()
    {
        // Save, Edit or Whatever
        //...

        return new EmptyResult(); // no need to return since the user will be redirected by the filter
    }
```

Extra: Read [How to redirect from a action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute) if you dislike to use Route names to redirect.

Comment: Thanks, @DouglasGandini. Can you point me to an example of this? Some code always helps :)

Comment: For sure! I've edited my answer and put some sample code.

Comment: Thanks again, @DouglasGandini. A follow-up: Can the above technique also be used to set the values on an `ActionLink` in the Edit view, so it knows where the "Back to List" button goes?

Comment: You can access the ViewBag (filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ControllerName) from your filter and store values (e.g. Controller and Action names) to be used inside your View (Html.ActionLink("Back to List", (string)ViewBag.ActionName, (string)ViewBag.ControllerName)). Depending of your architecture you'll need to create another ActionFilter to do this.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, @DouglasGandini.

Comment: Got one more question, @DouglasGandini: The Edit button on the partial view takes the user to the GET Edit action, which displays the record from `Controller1/Edit`. I need to do the redirect when the user does the POST Edit action; by then, wouldn't the `UrlReferrer` be this same controller rather than the originating page that contains the partial view?

Comment: In this scenario the url in UrlReferer will be the same as the post target. I think it is not a issue because the redirect will be made as a GET request.

Answer (score 3):

There are two aspects to this:

- The "Back to List" link
- The "Save/Delete" actions

As far as the "Back to List" link, your controller should be giving the view all the information it needs to produce a viable GUI. Pass an identifier (or even the actual return URL) to the view in the ViewBag as a dynamic property and let the view render the link to the destination.

For the "Save/Delete" actions, it depends on how they are implemented.

If it's all JS with http requests then the same concept above applies.

If you are posting back to the server however, the controller will have to do the redirection with something like `RedirectToAction()`.

Comment: Actually, "Back to List" on the partial view is now in a different controller, so it won't know about the originating controller. If I click it, it'll send me to `Controller1/Index`

Comment: It doesn't matter where it's at, that is why it's a partial view. All that matters is that you tell it where it needs to point to and that is something the controller knows because it's processing the original action. Read my answer one more time and let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: By the way, try putting your partial views in a neutral folder to avoid confusion. Common practice is to place them in Views/Shared.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the previous location in a [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx) and then populate your button href with the [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx) content...

Or

You can use [Url Referrer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx), which fectches the previous url that linked to current page.

Of course the best method will depend on your implementantion, without seeing your code those two are the best option that I can think of.

Comment: Isn't `ViewBag` per controller or can a different controller (`Controller1`) read it? Maybe I'm confused how that will work.

Comment: My bad, you're right Viewbag is limited to the controller and it holds the value in a single request. If you want to transport the data from one controller to another you'll need to use either TempData or Session.

Is you calling a Controller2 directly from Controller1?