# ASP.NET Core: [Policy based Authorization] No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I use policy-based authentication to provide access based on menu rights to logged in user. If the menu has access then I call `context.Succeed(requirement);` but on error (unauthorized menu access), I want to redirect it to the home page. How can I achieve that in `filterContext.Result`?
Here is my Code:

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement) {
    var filterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
    var sessionObj = SessionManager.GetObjectFromJson<AuthenticateUserInfo>(filterContext.HttpContext.Session, "oLoginModel");
    if (context.User == null)
    {
        // no user authorizedd. Alternatively call context.Fail() to ensure a failure 
        // as another handler for this requirement may succeed
        context.Fail();
        //filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Login", action = "LogOn" }));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    //var obj = context.Requirements.
    bool hasPermission = sessionObj == null ? false : sessionObj.Menus.Any(m => m.ControllerName == requirement.ControllerName); //.Any(= requirement.ControllerName);
    if (hasPermission)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    else
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "" }));
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I refer [Redirect From Action Filter Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute) link but it's for ASP.NET MVC and I already implemented in MVC but not working in MVC Core.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect From Action Filter Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute)

Comment: With policy-based auth, your setting of `Result` is overridden by `AuthorizeFilter`, which sets it to `ChallengeResult` or `ForbidResult` depending on the failure scenario (unauthenticated vs. unauthorized). This delegates the behavior to the authentication system. You need to register an authentication handler that implements the challenge and/or forbid logic with the behavior you want.

Comment: @nlawalker, thank you for your suggestion. Can you please provide some examples related it? how to implements the challenge and/or forbid logic in AuthorizeFilter.

Comment: @SanketS [this](https://joonasw.net/view/creating-auth-scheme-in-aspnet-core-2) might get you started; it shows how to build and register a custom authentication handler/scheme. For yours, you'd need to implement HandleChallengeAsync and/or HandleForbiddenAsync to perform the appropriate redirect. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x) about using a specific scheme when authorizing.