# Redirect to AccessDenied page when user is not authorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I have created a custom AuthorizationAttribute which I'm placing on my controllers. I followed [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554094/asp-net-mvc-adding-to-the-authorize-attribute). I've implemented custom authorization logic in the OnAuthorization method and this works fine. When the user fails authorization I'm currently doing the following:

```
// if authorization check fails...
filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

This displays a username/password prompt.

My question is what is the recommended way send the user to a "Access Is Denied" type page when they fail authorization?

I am using MVC3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went for a straight redirect:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
...
// if authorization check fails...
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(AccessDeniedPage);
```

**Edit:** Rob Conery has a very good article describing this in detail with [ASP.NET MVC: Securing Your Controller Actions](http://wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-securing-your-controller-actions)

Answer (score 4):

On the login page, you can check if the user is already logged in and display an access denied message instead of the login prompt.

Comment: While this might work on a single site, this solution doesn't work at all for a single sign-on system unless you want the Security Token Service to implicitly understand all of the roles/user access rights to your Relying Party sites which would be very incorrect IMO.

Answer (score 1):

you can throw [HttpException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx) with error code `401`