# Redirect to another page when user is not authorized in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've read

[How to easily redirect if not authenticated in MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770563/how-to-easily-redirect-if-not-authenticated-in-mvc-3) and 
[Redirect to AccessDenied page when user is not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329524/redirect-to-accessdenied-page-when-user-is-not-authorized) but the link from an answer (means http://wekeroad.com/2008/03/12/aspnet-mvc-securing-your-controller-actions/) doesn't work.

I put

```
[Authorize(Users = "test")]
    public class RestrictedPageController: Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }

 ....
    }
```

And in my web.config, I have already

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>
```

accordingly with https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770583/998696

But when I want to access `/RestrictedPage/Index`, it must redirect me to other page (from other controller). Instead of this, the error appears like:

```
Server Error in '/Project' Application.

The view 'LogOn' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Account/LogOn.aspx
~/Views/Account/LogOn.ascx
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.aspx
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.ascx
~/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml
~/Views/Account/LogOn.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/LogOn.vbhtml
```

Before login, the `Logon` page form appears correctly but the above error appears when accessing `/RestrictedPage/Index` page. I can login with user different one authorized to access `RestrictedPage` page.

Where is my mistake and how setup redirection ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The default `Authorize` attribute behaves in such a way that when the user is *not authenticated* or *authenticated but not authorized* then it set the status code as **401 (UnAuthorized)**. When the filter sets the status code as **401**  the ASP.NET framework checks if the website has forms authentication enabled and if it is then redirects to `loginUrl` parameter set up there.

If you want to change that behavior say you want to redirect the user to an `AccessDenied` controller if the user is authenticated but not authorized then you have to extend the `Authorize` attribute and override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method.

For ex.

```
public class CustomAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
        else
        {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new 
               RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "AccessDenied" }));
        }
    }
}
```

You can override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` as per your need and then you have to mark the controller actions to use the `CustomAuthorize` attribute instead of the built-in one.

Comment: Upvote and accepted! One remarks: must use `protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest( AuthorizationContext filterContext ) {` to override the method, otherwise won't work

Comment: This is the one solution I keep running into, but is this really still the only way to do it? Having to recreate the `[Authorize]` filter just to change the path seems overkill.

Comment: If you want to need authorization across your project then add this line to AppStart/FilterConfig:
`filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());`

Answer (score 7):

I like Mark's Answer, 
but I don't want to change all of my action attributes
from [Authorize] to [CustomAuthorize]

I edit `Login()` action on `AccountController`
and check `Request.IsAuthenticated` before show view
I think, if the authenticated user go to `/Account/Logon`, 
I will redirect to `/Error/AccessDenied`.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: but in this case, if you are already logged in and go to login page, you will see a `/error/accessDenied` instead of `/account/login`, right?

If you don't wish to change `[Authorize]` to `[CustomAuthorize]` you can always name it `YourBrand.YourProject.Security.AuthorizeAttribute` and then only make a reference to `YourBrand.YourProject.Security` or something

Comment: I like this solution, but if they are already authenticated but not authorized, then I would redirect to a non-error home page where everyone is authorized, and include an optional ViewBag status message that says something like $"You are not authorized to view {returnUrl}".

Answer (score 3):

Since I did not want to override `AuthorizeAttribute` I used filter

```
public class RedirectFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        if (!IsAuthorized(filterContext))
        {
            filterContext.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "AccessDenied"}));
        }
    }

    private bool IsAuthorized(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var descriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var authorizeAttr = descriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as AuthorizeAttribute;

        if (authorizeAttr != null)
        {
            if(!authorizeAttr.Users.Contains(filterContext.HttpContext.User.ToString()))
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place "/Account/LogOn" Instead of "~/Account/LogOn"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct as you mentioned in web.config

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
```

redirection is looking for Account controller and LogOn actionresult.  If you want to redirect your page, change there instead of account and logon