# MVC5 custom error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to show custom error page when user tries to call controller methods which does not exist or authorization error occurs during access in MVC5 web application.

Is there any site which explains how to setup custom error page for MVC5 website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928277/redirect-to-another-page-when-user-is-not-authorized-in-asp-net-mvc3)

Answer (score 1):

Add following `<customErrors>` tag in the web.config that helps you to redirect to the `NotFound` action method of `Error` controller if the system fails to find the requested url (status code 404) and redirects to `ServerError` action method of error controller if the system fires an internal server error (status code 500)

```
<!--<Redirect to error page>-->
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/ServerError">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
<!--</Redirect to error page>-->
```

You have to create an `Error` controller that contains `ServerError` and `NotFound` action method that renders the related view to display the proper message to the user.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't redirect on error pages. Using `<error redirect="" />` is only permissable if you also have `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page by Ben Foster, very detailed explanation of the issues you will encounter and a solid solution. 
http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer you can handle errors in globalasax Application_Error() method like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();

    string redirectUrl = "/Error"; // default
    if (exception is HttpException) {
        if (((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode() == 404) {
            redirectUrl += "/NotFound";
        } else if (((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode() == 401) {
            redirectUrl += "/NotAuthorized";
        } else { 
            redirectUrl += "?e=" + ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode();
        }
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Clear();
    }
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```