# ASP.NET MVC5 Custom Errors hitting 500 instead of 400, 403 or 404

Tags: c#, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, custom-errors

I have setup Custom Errors for my site as my Web.config shows below:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error400">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/Error404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Error403" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Error500" />
    </customErrors>   
</system.web>
```

And also

```
<system.webServer>  
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="400" />
        <error statusCode="400" path="/Error/Error400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <remove statusCode="403" />
        <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/Error403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Error404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />      
        <remove statusCode="500" />
        <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Error500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I am throwing errors like this from my controllers:

```
throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "The checklist Id is not specified. EntityId: " + this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId + "; userId: " + this.LoggedInUser.UserId);
```

The Error controller that handles the custom error page requests is:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Error400()
    {
        ErrorViewModel error = new ErrorViewModel();
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return View(error);
    }

    public ActionResult Error403()
    {
        ErrorViewModel error = new ErrorViewModel();
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        return View(error);
    }

    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        ErrorViewModel error = new ErrorViewModel();
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return View(error);
    }

    public ActionResult Error500()
    {
        ErrorViewModel error = new ErrorViewModel();
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return View(error);
    }
}
```

However, in the example thrown exception which is a 400 Error, the 400 action doesn't get called. Instead, the 500 action gets called. How can I make it call the correct 400 action instead for the thrown error?

I am using ELMAH for my error logging and it is showing the correct error code:
[image: Elmah log]

Comment: **Never** redirect users to show error pages that have corresponding HTTP status codes.

Comment: I'm not. They are custom error pages. They only see a nice message.

Comment: Your `system.web` error pages are set to `redirect="..."`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm doing that as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685737/mvc5-custom-error-page and http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

Comment: Your answer hasn't helped answer my question at all. Can I please get some more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following answer, ResponseRewrite won't work with MVC routes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770265/758765

If you read through Bens (awesome) blog post, he's using actual files to represent the 404 and 500 responses and not an MVC controller.

Comment: Thanks for this. It does seem rather silly, but Ben's method works.