# Use [Authorize] Attribute to Redirect to Register instead of Login with ASP.net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm sending users a link to a page in my application that will require them to authorize. These are first-time visitors, so I'd like to redirect them to Register instead of Login.

My controller action is in the form of:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I found several similar posts here but none that used ASP.net Identity. Ideally this would be something I could set in web.config like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Controller/Action" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you: [Redirect to another page when user is not authorized in asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928277/redirect-to-another-page-when-user-is-not-authorized-in-asp-net-mvc3).

You can create custom authorize attribute which will redirect a user to desired page