# Handle Authorization policy in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Sample Code:

```
[Authorize(Policy = Authorization.Approvers)]
[HttpPost]
[Route("/status/approve")]

public void method1

{
//action
}
```

When a person is not part of approvers, it errors out. How to handle or redirect without getting a 404 not found on angular side.

Comment: Try this one method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928277/redirect-to-another-page-when-user-is-not-authorized-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: Ok. Thank you Martin