# Authentication from Asp.Net 2.0 to Asp.Net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

We have an existing application written in asp.net 2.0. Then we created a new module using mvc3 which is obviously asp.net 4.0. Is there someone who tried having authentication from 2.0 submitted to the mvc3 site to be able to access the mvc3 page? Thanks!

Comment: are not asp.net 4.0 and mvc 3 completely different things?

Comment: @naveen - Yes, different things. But he is right - MVC3 uses .NET 4.0 features.

Comment: see n feel a difference.[link](http://www.mindstick.com/Blog/185/Difference%20between%20ASP%20NET%20and%20ASP%20NET%20MVC)

Comment: @Badz: are you rolling out your own authentication or using a the default forms authentication?

Comment: Using default form authentication by mvc3. The problem is I'm not sure how to or what should I do to have something from the 2.0 program to be authenticated by the mvc3 page

Comment: please post exact error you recieving, do you have YoD ?

Comment: Look at the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554094/asp-net-mvc-adding-to-the-authorize-attribute

Comment: No I have no errors, I'm just asking if someone has tried. I'm looking for an idea

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following link:
[asp.net mvc Adding to the AUTHORIZE attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554094/asp-net-mvc-adding-to-the-authorize-attribute)

It should answer your question.

Basically you have to create an attribute class derived from AuthorizeAttribute

And then you can use this attribute with your controller class like:

```
[YourAuthorization(Roles = "Admin", ViewName="AccessDenied")]
public class YourControllerController : Controller
```